# get the new value based on the last row and checking the ID

Tags: python, pandas

The current dateframe.

```
ID  Date     Start Value    Payment
111 1/1/2018    1000        0
111 1/2/2018                100
111 1/3/2018                500
111 1/4/2018                400
111 1/5/2018                0
222 4/1/2018    2000        200
222 4/2/2018                100
222 4/3/2018                700
222 4/4/2018                0
222 4/5/2018                0
222 4/6/2018                1000
222 4/7/2018                0
```

This is the dataframe what I am trying to get. Basically, i am trying to fill the star value for each row. AS you can see, every ID has a start value on the first day. next day's start value = last day's start value - last day's payment.

```
   ID   Date    Start Value     Payment
    111 1/1/2018    1000        0
    111 1/2/2018    1000        100
    111 1/3/2018    900         500
    111 1/4/2018    400         400
    111 1/5/2018    0           0
    222 4/1/2018    2000        200
    222 4/2/2018    1800        100
    222 4/3/2018    1700        700
    222 4/4/2018    1000        0
    222 4/5/2018    1000        0
    222 4/6/2018    1000        1000
    222 4/7/2018    0           0
```

Right now, I use Excel with this formula. 
Start Value = if(ID in this row == ID in last row, last row's start value - last row's payment, Start Value)

It works well, I am wondering if I can do it in Python/Pandas. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can using `groupby` and `shift` + `cumsum`, `ffill` will setting up initial value for all row under the same Id, then we just need to deduct the cumulative payment from that row till the start , we get the remaining value at that point

```
df.StartValue.fillna(df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x : x['StartValue'].ffill()-x['Payment'].shift().cumsum()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True))
Out[61]: 
0     1000.0
1     1000.0
2      900.0
3      400.0
4        0.0
5     2000.0
6     1800.0
7     1700.0
8     1000.0
9     1000.0
10    1000.0
11       0.0
Name: StartValue, dtype: float64
```

Assign it back by adding `inplace=Ture`

```
df.StartValue.fillna(df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x : x['StartValue'].ffill()-x['Payment'].shift().cumsum()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True),inplace=True)
df
Out[63]: 
     ID      Date  StartValue  Payment
0   111  1/1/2018      1000.0        0
1   111  1/2/2018      1000.0      100
2   111  1/3/2018       900.0      500
3   111  1/4/2018       400.0      400
4   111  1/5/2018         0.0        0
5   222  4/1/2018      2000.0      200
6   222  4/2/2018      1800.0      100
7   222  4/3/2018      1700.0      700
8   222  4/4/2018      1000.0        0
9   222  4/5/2018      1000.0        0
10  222  4/6/2018      1000.0     1000
11  222  4/7/2018         0.0        0
```

Comment: Hi Wen, thank you for your quick reply. could you please give me some ideas that how this part works `x['StartValue'].ffill()-x['Payment'].shift().cumsum()`? thanks.

Comment: @qqqwww yw :-) if this is what you need , would you like accept ?